# Controller Unit test not able to autowire required beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockmvc

I am trying to write a unit test for spring controller, the **myService** class is autowired in **myController**,I have mocked myService class but when I debug the code it is coming **null**

**myService = null**

I am not able to inject this service for my controller.

```
   @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class TestManageDevices {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Mock
        MyService myService;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MyController())
                    .build();
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldPass() throws Exception {
            Mockito.doNothing().when(myService).someMethod(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
            JobResponse jobResponse = JobResponse.builder().responseCode(0).build();
            jobResponse.requestObj = "mockedStringObject";

            RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/pathfortest")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .param("id", Mockito.anyString());

            MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();


            System.out.println(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());

            MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();


            Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), response.getStatus());

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are newing up the controller manually with `new MyController()` in the `setUp` method, so dependencies are not being injected.

Create a variable of type controller

```
@InjectMocks
MyController myController;
```

Use this when creating `mockMVC` instance in your `setUp` method as below:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();
```

This should work.